# c# how to get all unique combinations of a list of objects and their frequency

Tags: c#, list, filtering

So in c# i'm trying to sort a list of objects so that i can get every unique combination and there count of how frequent they happen in the list.

This list i have is as following:

```
    List<Numbers> nums = new List<Numbers>();

    public class Numbers
    {
        public int numOne { get; set; }
        public int numTwo { get; set; }
    }

    nums.Add(new Numbers { numOne = 1, numTwo = 2});
    nums.Add(new Numbers { numOne = 4, numTwo = 7});
    nums.Add(new Numbers { numOne = 1, numTwo = 2});
```

Now i want to achieve a new list that basicly filters the "nums" list so that i have following result:

```
    1  |  2  -->  2
    4  |  7  -->  1
```

I've been experimenting with linq but i can't seem to find the right way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: *"I've been experimenting with linq"* would you show us what you've done so far ?

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8 I quote "If you want to return distinct elements from sequences of objects of some custom data type, you have to implement the IEquatable<T> generic interface in the class. The following code example shows how to implement this interface in a custom data type"

Comment: You can use linq [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8) method

Comment: What would be the expected result if you add this : `nums.Add(new Numbers { numOne = 7, numTwo = 1});`

Comment: @AleksAndreev implementing `IEquatable` is more helpful as coding advances, sooner or later it would prove better.

Comment: Querying with Distinct() comes to mind and then iterating that list with a Count() comes to mind. There are probably many ways to skin this one.

Comment: @bradbury9 yes, OP can implement `IEquatable` and use `Distinct` but this will only get unique items, not frequency

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out. Using LINQ, You are able to group your list of nums by `numOne` and `numTwo` at once. Then you can select the properties and figure out the count by selecting the `Count` of values in the nums list where the groupby conditions were met. You can then use it however you see fit. I just printed it out to a console window and accessed the properties the same way you would a normal list. Hope this help.

```
var filtered = nums.GroupBy(n => new { n.numOne, n.numTwo })
                   .Select(x => new
                   {
                       x.Key.numOne,
                       x.Key.numTwo,
                       count = x.Count()
                   })
                   .ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < filtered.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} | {1} --> {2}", 
                        filtered[i].numOne, 
                        filtered[i].numTwo, 
                        filtered[i].count));
```

Comment: You can simplify `count` calculation. Just use `count = x.Count()`

Comment: Good point. I will edit that. A ton easier to read and probably quicker.